# Find duplicated (with something add to one of the duplicate) and then keep the one with no NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello I have a df such as :

```
                                                  COL3 COL2 COL4
scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus               <NA> <NA> <NA>
scaffold_15158_6288.9804_.__Canis_lupus           <NA>    S  N.S
scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus.1             <NA>  N.S  N.S
JZSA01004450.1_76460.78230_.__Cattus_norvegicus   <NA>  N.S  N.S
JZSA01000885.1_12137.15233_.__Cattus_norvegicus   <NA>    S  N.S
scaffold_2503_10731.14478_.__DOnkey_p <NA>  N.S  N.S
IDBA_scaffold_5653_1292.5210_.__Cattus_domesticus <NA>  N.S  N.S
scf7180005154334_13722.16701_.__Cattus_cattus     <NA>  N.S  N.S
scf7180005155932_0.1647_.__Cattus_cattus          <NA>  N.S  N.S
scaffold_102_40302.44454_.__poulpus      <NA>    S    S
scaffold_2103_2565.6351_.__Oryctolagus_cuniculus  <NA>    S    S
Wolbachia1                                        <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

and I would like to :

1. find duplicated element in first column : here `scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus` and `scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus.1`  are duplicated excepted that the last one have a `.Number` at the end (the number can change).
2. Keep the row with no `NA` value in `COL4`
3. and remove the `.Number` part in `Col1`.

here I should get a final df such as :

```
                                 COL3 COL2 COL4
scaffold_15158_6288.9804_.__Canis_lupus           <NA>    S  N.S
scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus               <NA>  N.S  N.S
JZSA01004450.1_76460.78230_.__Cattus_norvegicus   <NA>  N.S  N.S
JZSA01000885.1_12137.15233_.__Cattus_norvegicus   <NA>    S  N.S
scaffold_2503_10731.14478_.__DOnkey_p <NA>  N.S  N.S
IDBA_scaffold_5653_1292.5210_.__Cattus_domesticus <NA>  N.S  N.S
scf7180005154334_13722.16701_.__Cattus_cattus     <NA>  N.S  N.S
scf7180005155932_0.1647_.__Cattus_cattus          <NA>  N.S  N.S
scaffold_102_40302.44454_.__poulpus      <NA>    S    S
scaffold_2103_2565.6351_.__Oryctolagus_cuniculus  <NA>    S    S
Wolbachia1                                        <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Thank you very much for your help

The data

```
 df<-structure(list(COL3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "NA", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), COL2 = c(NA, "S", 
    "N.S", "N.S", 
    "S", "N.S", 
    "N.S", "N.S", 
    "N.S", "S", 
    "S", NA), COL4 = c(NA, "N.S", 
    "N.S", "N.S", 
    "N.S", "N.S", 
    "N.S", "N.S", 
    "N.S", "S", 
    "S", NA)), row.names = c("scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus", 
    "scaffold_15158_6288.9804_.__Canis_lupus", "scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus.1", 
    "JZSA01004450.1_76460.78230_.__Cattus_norvegicus", "JZSA01000885.1_12137.15233_.__Cattus_norvegicus", 
    "scaffold_2503_10731.14478_.__DOnkey_p", "IDBA_scaffold_5653_1292.5210_.__Cattus_domesticus", 
    "scf7180005154334_13722.16701_.__Cattus_cattus", "scf7180005155932_0.1647_.__Cattus_cattus", 
    "scaffold_102_40302.44454_.__poulpus", "scaffold_2103_2565.6351_.__Oryctolagus_cuniculus", 
    "Wolbachia1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Response to **Datalowe**

with you code I get a output such as :

```
                                                  COL3 COL2 COL4
scaffold_15158_6288.9804_.__Canis_lupus           <NA>    S  N.S
scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus               <NA>  N.S  N.S
JZSA01004450.1_76460.78230_.__Cattus_norvegicus     NA  N.S  N.S
JZSA01000885.1_12137.15233_.__Cattus_norvegicus   <NA>    S  N.S
scaffold_2503_10731.14478_.__DOnkey_p             <NA>  N.S  N.S
IDBA_scaffold_5653_1292.5210_.__Cattus_domesticus <NA>  N.S  N.S
scf7180005154334_13722.16701_.__Cattus_cattus     <NA>  N.S  N.S
scf7180005155932_0.1647_.__Cattus_cattus          <NA>  N.S  N.S
scaffold_102_40302.44454_.__poulpus               <NA>    S    S
scaffold_2103_2565.6351_.__Oryctolagus_cuniculus  <NA>    S    S
```

instead of

```
                                                  COL3 COL2 COL4
scaffold_15158_6288.9804_.__Canis_lupus           <NA>    S  N.S
scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus               <NA>  N.S  N.S
JZSA01004450.1_76460.78230_.__Cattus_norvegicus     NA  N.S  N.S
JZSA01000885.1_12137.15233_.__Cattus_norvegicus   <NA>    S  N.S
scaffold_2503_10731.14478_.__DOnkey_p             <NA>  N.S  N.S
IDBA_scaffold_5653_1292.5210_.__Cattus_domesticus <NA>  N.S  N.S
scf7180005154334_13722.16701_.__Cattus_cattus     <NA>  N.S  N.S
scf7180005155932_0.1647_.__Cattus_cattus          <NA>  N.S  N.S
scaffold_102_40302.44454_.__poulpus               <NA>    S    S
scaffold_2103_2565.6351_.__Oryctolagus_cuniculus  <NA>    S    S
Wolbachia1                                        <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Wolbachia disappeared

Comment: How are you reading in the data? It makes things a little bit simpler for you if you, instead of starting out with the animal codes as row names would have them in a column of their own. Also do you want `Wolbachia1` changed to `Wolfbachia`, or should those numbers stay?

Comment: But at the end I need the same structure with the rownames as in the final expected result.  No only duplicated onces need to remove the ```.Number```, so for ```Wolbachia1```the number stays :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df<-structure(list(COL3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "NA", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), COL2 = c(NA, "S", 
    "N.S", "N.S", 
    "S", "N.S", 
    "N.S", "N.S", 
    "N.S", "S", 
    "S", NA), COL4 = c(NA, "N.S", 
    "N.S", "N.S", 
    "N.S", "N.S", 
    "N.S", "N.S", 
    "N.S", "S", 
    "S", NA)), row.names = c("scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus", 
    "scaffold_15158_6288.9804_.__Canis_lupus", "scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus.1", 
    "JZSA01004450.1_76460.78230_.__Cattus_norvegicus", "JZSA01000885.1_12137.15233_.__Cattus_norvegicus", 
    "scaffold_2503_10731.14478_.__DOnkey_p", "IDBA_scaffold_5653_1292.5210_.__Cattus_domesticus", 
    "scf7180005154334_13722.16701_.__Cattus_cattus", "scf7180005155932_0.1647_.__Cattus_cattus", 
    "scaffold_102_40302.44454_.__poulpus", "scaffold_2103_2565.6351_.__Oryctolagus_cuniculus", 
    "Wolbachia1"), class = "data.frame")

# make a vector of animal codes, where the trailing ".<number>" part has been removed
cleaned_animal_codes <- sub("\\.[0-9]+$", "", row.names(df))

# find names of duplicated animal codes
dupl_acodes <- cleaned_animal_codes[duplicated(cleaned_animal_codes)]

# find rows which have unique animal codes
keep_bool <- !cleaned_animal_codes %in% dupl_acodes

# rows that have a duplicate, BUT have a non-NA value in COL4, should be kept
keep_bool <- keep_bool | !is.na(df$COL4)

# apply the filter
cleaned_df <- df[keep_bool, ]

# use the filter again to replace the row names with the trailing <.digits> pattern removed
row.names(cleaned_df) <- cleaned_animal_codes[keep_bool]
```

```
print(cleaned_df)
                                                  COL3 COL2 COL4
scaffold_15158_6288.9804_.__Canis_lupus           <NA>    S  N.S
scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus               <NA>  N.S  N.S
JZSA01004450.1_76460.78230_.__Cattus_norvegicus     NA  N.S  N.S
JZSA01000885.1_12137.15233_.__Cattus_norvegicus   <NA>    S  N.S
scaffold_2503_10731.14478_.__DOnkey_p             <NA>  N.S  N.S
IDBA_scaffold_5653_1292.5210_.__Cattus_domesticus <NA>  N.S  N.S
scf7180005154334_13722.16701_.__Cattus_cattus     <NA>  N.S  N.S
scf7180005155932_0.1647_.__Cattus_cattus          <NA>  N.S  N.S
scaffold_102_40302.44454_.__poulpus               <NA>    S    S
scaffold_2103_2565.6351_.__Oryctolagus_cuniculus  <NA>    S    S
Wolbachia1                                        <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Use ?sub and ?duplicated in the R console to find out more about these commands. For sub, you can also look at online tutorials ([example](https://regexone.com/)) about regular expressions, and/or read specifically about [regular expressions are used in R](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html#matching-patterns-with-regular-expressions).

Comment: Thank you very much but Wolbachia disappeared why ? I edited my post to show you the result I get with my data and what I need to get

Comment: You described that you wanted to "Keep the row with no NA value in COL4", ie remove rows that have a NA value in the fourth column. The "Wolbachia1" row has an NA value for COL4, and so it is removed. Is this not what you wanted? (I changed Wolbachia1's COL4 value in my modification of the example, for this very reason)

Comment: Ho ok it is a misanderstood, I meant keep the row wit no NA value in COL4 for duplicated values

Comment: Ah. I updated my answer, hopefully it works now. Note that if there are duplicates, but ALL of them have NA values in COL4, none will be kept. You didn't describe what should happen in that case, so it wasn't possible to specify what should be done then. Hope it's useful in either case.

Comment: Whoops, I noticed I'd confused myself a bit there. Now I've updated the code so that it works properly (the previous version of the code didn't make sure that the first row in each set of duplicates was marked as such, because the `duplicated` function only marks repetitions of previously occurring values, not all occurrence of repeated values)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn rownames into a separate column, remove `.number` part and select first non-NA value in each of the `COL` column.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column('col') %>%
  group_by(col = sub('\\.\\d+$', '\\1', col)) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('COL'), ~na.omit(.)[1]))

# A tibble: 11 x 4
#   col                                               COL3  COL2  COL4 
#   <chr>                                             <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 IDBA_scaffold_5653_1292.5210_.__Cattus_domesticus NA    N.S   N.S  
# 2 JZSA01000885.1_12137.15233_.__Cattus_norvegicus   NA    S     N.S  
# 3 JZSA01004450.1_76460.78230_.__Cattus_norvegicus   NA    N.S   N.S  
# 4 scaffold_102_40302.44454_.__poulpus               NA    S     S    
# 5 scaffold_15158_6288.9804_.__Canis_lupus           NA    S     N.S  
# 6 scaffold_2103_2565.6351_.__Oryctolagus_cuniculus  NA    S     S    
# 7 scaffold_2503_10731.14478_.__DOnkey_p             NA    N.S   N.S  
# 8 scaffold_7180.2.BICs_.__Canis_lupus               NA    N.S   N.S  
# 9 scf7180005154334_13722.16701_.__Cattus_cattus     NA    N.S   N.S  
#10 scf7180005155932_0.1647_.__Cattus_cattus          NA    N.S   N.S  
#11 Wolbachia1                                        NA    NA    NA
```